# How to check if a specific type exists in a python dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

How to check if a specific type exists in a dictionary? No matter what level this is in. I want to do the search both in the keys and values set.

For example, I want to find out the dictionary key that is a np.int64.

Answer (score 0):

I'd loop over the dict with a for loop and check one-by-one:

```
some_dict = {1:"one",
             2:"Two",
             3:"Three",}

for key, value in some_dict.items():
     if isinstanceof(value, np.int64):
         print("Found one! it is {}:{}".format(key, value))
```

This wil check every one, one-by-one. Here is a list of sources to look into. That way you'll know why it works:

- [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops/3294899#3294899)
- [https://pynative.com/python-isinstance-explained-with-examples/#:~:text=The%20Python%E2%80%99s%20isinstance%20%28%29%20function%20checks%20whether%20the,Also%2C%20Solve%3A%20Python%20Basic%20Exercise%20and%20Beginners%20Quiz](https://pynative.com/python-isinstance-explained-with-examples/#:%7E:text=The%20Python%E2%80%99s%20isinstance%20%28%29%20function%20checks%20whether%20the,Also%2C%20Solve%3A%20Python%20Basic%20Exercise%20and%20Beginners%20Quiz)

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer, my problem is I have many nested levels :(

Comment: If you have many nested levels, could you provide an example? To better understand the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion for nested dicts

```
def recur(dct, type_ref):
    for k,v in dct.items():
        if isinstance(v, type_ref) or isinstance(k, type_ref):
            print(k,v)
            return True
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            return recur(v, type_ref)
    return False
# dct = input dict, type_ref = type you want to match
```

Not sure if this is exactly what you want since you haven't provided much information